# How to exclude a document if two fields are the same?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, aggregation-framework

After performing some aggregation magic, I have arrived at this data:

```
{ "_id" : "5700edfe03fcdb000347bebb", "size" : 3, "count" : 2 }
{ "_id" : "5700edfe03fcdb000347bebf", "size" : 2, "count" : 2 }
```

Now, I want to eliminate all the entries where size is equal to count.

So I ran this aggregation instruction:

```
match3 = { "$match" : { "size" : { "$ne" : "count"}  } }
```

But it doesn't eliminate anything and returns the two lines as it is.

I want the result to be just this one line as it is the only one where size is not equal to count:

```
{ "_id" : "5700edfe03fcdb000347bebb", "size" : 3, "count" : 2 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a [`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) stage to your aggregation pipeline:

```
{ "$redact": {
    "$cond": [ 
        { "$eq": [ "$size", "$count" ] },
        "$$PRUNE",
        "$$KEEP"
    ]
}}
```

Comment: While this answer is correct, is there a more efficient way of matching with $ne? The problem with using redact is that you first match by a certain criteria and for example, return 100 docs with that criteria. The you redact it in memory so it can be memory intensive. If you match it with the criteria and the $ne aggregation step, you could return 20 docs and that would save up on memory.

Comment: @Simon I am not sure I fully understand what you mean, but the problem here is that we need to compare the value of two fields in the document and we can't do this with `$match`.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `$where` operator for this

```
db.collection.find({ $where: "this.size != this.count" })
db.collection.remove({ $where: "this.size != this.count" })
```

UPDATE:
After I got downvoted I decided to compare the 2 solutions.
Both use a `COLLSCAN` and both return the same results.
So please enlighten me what is so wrong about my solution? :)